# gdaltools in qgis v2.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Where's the GDALTools plugin for QGIS 2.4? It's not listed in list of available plugins, and it's seemingly not installed out of the box. Is it just that it's not yet compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDALTools are a core plugin of QGIS, and will be installed by default.

If you are missing some parts of the Vector, Raster or Processing menu, please add a screenshot.

Comment: There's supposed to be a processing menu?

Comment: Yes, formerly known as Sextante. It might be turned off when the processing plugin is disabled. GDALTools should appear in the list of **installed** plugins too, both with Install/Reinstall/Uninstall greyed out. If not, there is something wrong with your installation.

Comment: Reinstalled and now I've got a full Raster menu and the missing Processing menu. I really had no way to know that they were missing until you let me know that they should have been there. Thanks!